# DataTables + KnockoutJS: "No data in the table" and sorting issues

Tags: knockout.js, datatables, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

As I've mentioned in the following question: [How do I pass an ID from View to the ViewModel as a parameter for GET function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848811/how-do-i-pass-an-id-from-view-to-the-viewmodel-as-a-parameter-for-get-function) I'm developing an MVC application, using MVC4, knockoutJS, Web API, Bootstrap, MSSQL Server 2012 and so forth. I'm using DataTables jQuery library for creating tables and binding them with data from the DB using knockoutJS. The following two issues are occuring: when I bind the table with a data-bind="foreach: regionsListModel.regions", it populates my table, but it adds a row "No data in the table" at the end of it, in the table footer it says "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 results", no pagination, and when I try to filter the results it empties the table completely. The same happens when I sort a column with it's header.

I'll post the code snippets again.

ViewModel:

```
    var regionsModel = {
    regionId: ko.observable(),
    companyId: ko.observable(),
    name: ko.observable(),
    companyName: ko.observable()    
};

var regionsListModel = {
    regions: ko.observable()
};

function getRegions() {
    get(apiUrl + "Regions/GetRegions", {}, function (data) {
        regionsListModel.regions(data);
    });
}

function getRegion() {
    get(apiUrl + "Regions/GetRegion", { aiId: regionsModel.regionId() }, function (data) {
        regionsModel.regionId(data.RegionID);
        regionsModel.companyName(data.CompanyName);
        regionsModel.companyId(data.CompanyID);
        regionsModel.name(data.Name);
    });
}

function viewRegion() {
    $("#ViewRegionModal").modal('show');
    //regionsModel.regionId($('#ViewRegion').val());
    getRegion();
    return false;
}
```

Code for the view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive" id="dtable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 20px;">ID</th>
                                    <th>Region Name</th>
                                    <th>Company Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody data-bind="foreach: regionsListModel.regions">
                                <tr id="ViewRegion" data-toggle="modal" data-bind="click: viewRegion, value: RegionID">
                                    <td data-bind="text: RegionID"></td>
                                    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                                    <td data-bind="text: CompanyName"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

The picture of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XwYy.png

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Adding the code that calls the getRegions (it is located in the Regions.js file, and the ViewModel is placed in RegionsData.js, both are loaded when the page is loaded).

```
$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(regionsModel);

    getRegions();
    getCompanies();

    $("#NewRegionButton").click(function () {
        $("#NewRegionModal").modal('show');
        return false;
    });

    $("#ViewRegion").click(function () {
        $("#ViewRegionModal").modal('show');
        return false;
    });

    $("#NewRegionModalClose").click(function () {
        clearFields();
        $("#NewRegionModal").modal('hide');
        return false;
    });

    $("#NewRegionSave").click(function () {
        newRegion();
        $("#NewRegionModal").modal('hide');
        return false;
    });

    $("#ViewRegionClose").click(function () {
        $("#ViewRegionModal").modal('hide');
        return false;
    });

    $("#ViewRegionEdit").click(function () {
        $("#ViewRegionModal").modal('hide');
        $("#EditRegionModal").modal('show');
        return false;
    });

    $("#RegionUpdateSave").click(function () {
        updateRegion();
        $("#EditRegionModal").modal('hide');
        return false;
    });

    $("#ViewRegionEditClose").click(function () {
        clearFields();
        $("#EditRegionModal").modal('hide');
        return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Well, I'm looking for direction to solve the two issues that I've mentioned that are occurring.

Comment: It appears that `getRegions` never gets called. Also, `getRegion` appears to be the only thing that sets any values in `regionsModel`, yet the URL it loads from is dependent on one of those values.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I've just edited the post, and added the code where the function is called.

Comment: When I have had to do paging, sorting etc... I use koGrid and they have very useful articles on their site if you google koGrid or knockout js koGrid. I am currently using this to display a list of 10 out of 2000 items using pagination and I can add to the list or remove and everything works nicely because it is all knockout. I have tried using datatables but it was much harder for me than implementing koGrid.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've looked at koGrid, and it surely is interesting and could solve a lot of future problems as well as the current ones. There is also an idea that I do the DataTable without knockout, but to draw them from RegionsData.js file, using jQuery actions. I'll try it later today and post the results.

Comment: I've tried several approaches to using KO and DataTables, but haven't managed to make it work. Even with using jQuery to draw the table, or certain parts of the table, it's not working. I'll probably try to make do with KoGrid, but if anybody have other suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes to the same problem like I did, here's the solution, and it's completely knockout-free:

```
    function updateView() {
    $("#tableProblems").dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid dt-header'<'span6'f><'span6'>r>t<'row-fluid dt-footer'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "aaData": problemsModel.problems(),
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "ProblemID" },
            { "mDataProp": "CategoryName" },
            { "mDataProp": "DateOpenFormatted" },
            { "mDataProp": "DateClosedFormatted" },
            { "mDataProp": "ObjectName" },
            { "mDataProp": "Nickname" }
        ]
    });
}
```

I just used this part of code at the initialization of page, and when I do the get* function, I just call the updateView() function, on the View side, I left tbody completely empty, DataTables does the rest.

(This is an example of another component I'm developing, not the Regions, but the principle is the same)